# Custom response to authorization failure in Twisted Web

Tags: python, http, twisted, twisted.web

I'm using HTTP Digest Authentication in a web-server written using the Twisted framework for python. I want to control the page that the user sees when they press cancel in the authentication dialog box, this should be the text of the 401 response body that initiated the authentication. In Apache this can be overwritten use the ErrorDocument directive, in Twisted I cannot find a way to change the body of the 401.

The simplest thing that I can find is copying the contents of `twisted.web._auth.wrapper.py` into a local copy and rewriting the `UnauthorizedResource` class to change the content, then using a `MyHTTPAuthSessionWrapper` copy that creates the updated Resource. This seems a bit "icky". Is there a more direct / easier way than this?